# Jquery page turn with html or asp

Tags: jquery

I was asked by a client to create a bookflip (Page Turn) effect that did not require Flash. The imBookFlip plugin can load a book in an iframe or directly on the page. The book's pages can be set to turn when manually clicked only, begin auto flip (turn automatically) as soon as the html page loads, or begin auto flip when first page (front cover is clicked).

Answer (score 1):

well you are in luck today my friend. Here is a [complete tutorial](http://www.sitepoint.com/newsletter/viewissue.php?id=5&issue=35&format=html#7) on how to get it done.

Comment: i know that thats not real page turn effect.
i want more realastic

Comment: I would say if you want more realistic effect you would have to bring the from this demo and reconstruct it in canvas element. Remember you will need excanvas compatible script so it works in ie too. best of luck.